# Formatting and color of values of objects logged in chrome devtools is unreadable in dark mode

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, debug-logs, browser, lightning-web-security

After the Winter 23' release added Lightning Web Security I started having a problem viewing the values of JavaScript objects.

Correct me if I'm wrong but to debug LWC in chrome devtools with [LWS enabled](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.security_lwsec_enable) you have to enable [debug mode](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.debug_mode_enable) in salesforce settings and also [enable the custom formatter](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.debug_dev_tools) in the chrome devtools. Without those options enabled JavaScript objects logged in console just show as proxy objects with no values inside.

With both of those options enabled I'm able to see the values of logged objects, but here comes the formatting problem.

In light mode everything looks fine

[image: Light mode devtools]

but after enabling dark mode in the chrome devtools most of the object values become unreadable.

[image: Dark mode devtools]

As far as I know there is no default custom formatter so Salesforce has to provide one. Is there any way to edit that? Or any other way to view logged values of objects, with dark mode enabled, so they become readable?

I know that I can disable the LWS feature, but that's just a short term solution. LWS is going to slowly roll out and eventaully replace the Lightning Locker entirely.